# How to change runs of values in a column with Perl, Python or bash

Tags: python, perl, bash

I want to iterate through lots of tab-delimited files and change a single column in the following way:

ORIGINAL

```
Col1    Col2    ....
afawer  1
asdgf   1
aser    1
qwerq   10
a3awer  10
1sdgf   11
a55er   11
2wu9    12
asxwer  12
a2dgf   13
a1er    13
qperq   13
...
```

DESIRED REPLACEMENT

```
Col1    Col2    ....
afawer  1
asdgf   1
aser    1
qwerq   2
a3awer  2
1sdgf   3
a55er   3
2wu9    4
asxwer  4
a2dgf   5
a1er    5
qperq   5
...
```

Note that the run lengths in Col2 will vary substantially for each file, so the lengths cannot be hard-coded. Essentially, the pattern I want to replace is this:

> aaabbbbbccccdddd

where a, b, c and d could be any integers. The desired replacement is:

> 1112222233334444

and so on (i.e. a natural ordering of integers).

I'd like to do this with Python or Perl, or just using bash commands like `sed` if possible.

Comment: Could you please explain the pattern more?

Comment: The desired replacements are variable length runs of the natural ordering of numbers 1, 2, 3,... etc. The pattern to be replaced are runs of numbers that may be present in no particular order (although the number at each run should be unique), so '10' which is the second run in thing to be replaced, should not pop up again.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and describe the problems you are having, then we can help you. Stack Overflow is a place to get help when you are stuck with your own programming efforts, not a source of free programming labour.

Answer (score 1):

With Python, use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group rows on the second column, and a counter provided by [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

with open(inputfile, 'rb') as ifh, open(outputfile, 'wb') as ofh:
    reader = csv.reader(ifh, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(ofh, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(next(reader))  # copy across header

    for counter, (key, group) in enumerate(groupby(reader, itemgetter(1)), 1):
        for row in group:
            row[1] = counter
            writer.writerow(row)
```

This writes a new CSV file with the same data, except the second column is replaced by a counter (starting at 1) that increments every time the original value in column 2 changes.

Comment: That sounds like it should work. I will try it out. However, (sorry for lack of python knowledge) how can I do this for tab-delimited files rather than csv?

Comment: @oisyutat: This **is** for tab delimited files. The `csv` module handles generic *something*-delimited files here, and the reader and writer are both configured to use `\t` (tab) as the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you could say:

```
awk 'NR>1{if ($2 == prev) { $2 = a; } else { prev=$2; a=a+1; $2=a; }}1' OFS='\t' filename
```

For your input, it'd produce the following output:

```
Col1    Col2
afawer  1
asdgf   1
aser    1
qwerq   2
a3awer  2
1sdgf   3
a55er   3
2wu9    4
asxwer  4
a2dgf   5
a1er    5
qperq   5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple Perl solution. It just keeps track of the previous value of the second column and bumps the value of `$n` if it changes.

The program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line, and sends the modified data to `STDOUT`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print scalar <>; # Copy header line

my ($prev, $n) = (0, 0);
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /\t/;
  ($prev, $fields[1]) = ($fields[1], $fields[1] == $prev ? $n : ++$n);
  print join("\t", @fields), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To complete the three languages you asked for: Here is a version in Perl.
Works also if the Col2 Values repeat themselves later.
edit: I used a space as delimeter, replaced with a tab.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (INFILE, "<", "infile.csv");
my @lines = <INFILE>;
close INFILE;

open (OUTFILE, ">", "outfile.csv");
my %hash = ("Col2", "Col2"); #  To handle the Header
my $counter=0;

foreach my $currentLine (@lines)
{
    chomp $currentLine;
    my @fields = split (/\W+/, $currentLine);
    if (!exists $hash{$fields[1]})  # Have I not seen the Col2 value before?
    {
        $counter++;                 # If not, determine what to replace the value with. 
        $hash{$fields[1]} = $counter;
    }
    $fields[1] = $hash{$fields[1]}; # Replace with known replacement.

    print OUTFILE $fields[0],"\t",$fields[1],"\n";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile. Also, it produces only two columns of output, goes haywire if there are any punctuation characters in the data, and requires the header labels to be hard-coded into the program.

Comment: @Borodin: Well, you are indeed right about the compiling stuff. I am sorry for that, i tested it on another machine and did not bother to send it over to post but did just type it in. Concerning your other remarks: I did not bother to include all possibilities, shame on me. I did not expect to be showered in rep for my answer. But apart from missing "" and an l instead of L, it does what Op asked for. And, yes, i fully expected the Op to tune the general idea for their actual needs, i am not their code-monkey. Its not a very good answer, i give you that, but less than zero?

Comment: I thought it poor enough to warrant a down vote. If others disagree with me then your votes will increase.

Comment: @Borodin: There is a big step between 0 and -1. Not for you, i understand (and i see your answers are so detailed, you will likely never get even close), but downvoting below 0 means I should never have answered in the first place. Not only is my answer not really helping the Op, it is even hurting them. That is why the downvote bothered me. But whatever, i cannot buy anything from rep. And i just saw, you are the first person i have seen so far with more downvotes than upvotes cast (and what a margin), so i doubt that really concerns you. Keep up the good answering.

Comment: You must see that my vote shouldn't depend on the total that it leaves you with? I have to mark you down as your code doesn't solve the problem as it is posed: the ellipsis in the data clearly shows that there are actually many columns of data, and you are discarding all but the first two. I am not proud of my voting record, and am well aware that I upvote - especially questions - all too infrequently. My view tends to be overly black and white, so either an answer is right or it is not, so it gets nothing or a downvote. I welcome your comment as a reminder to consider up votes in every case.